# Collision and resulting compression

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

During collision is there any compression  of the surface? if yes, the collision is considered as elastic or non elastic ? Does the compression produce the impulse force or its due to the impulse force if compression occurs?

Comment: You need to be more specific as regards the material, as different materials compress , and probably rebound to their original shape, at different rates, depending on their molecular structure . You use the word bend but I think you mean compress.

Comment: Yes, I mean compress.

Comment: A compression of materials causes force? Not sure I follow.

Comment: So the forces causes the compression?